# magento 2 buyer review

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

i'm looking for magento 2.1.x extension:
I want to have an extension that contains buyer review. i mean that just real buyer can rate/review on product not anyone else.
i found this extension ytorbyk/magento2-buyer-review (https://github.com/ytorbyk/magento2-buyer-review) that says it will add a label on buyer reviews but after installation i didn't find anything... all reviews are same and cant find buyers.
if any body can help me to create an extension step by step to achieve that just buyer can rate/review please help. otherwise please check this module to find why it doesnt show the label. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you configured the extension settings under admin? There should be a tobai tab in admin which has the extension settings and we need to enabled there.

Comment: Yes i enabled it and set even new label text and all setting are ok. but it doesn't work. did you installed it?

Comment: No i haven't installed , have  you clear cache and deploy static content

Comment: Yes i am! i just add it and then upgrade,di compile, deploy, reindex, cache and also remove var/di but still doesn't exist in frontend